# Use of "tail" in blessing and cursing

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parts-of-the-body

> "וּנְתָנְךָ ה' לְרֹאשׁ וְלֹא לְזָנָב"
> "YHWH will make you the head, not the tail;" [Deuteronomy.28.13](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.28.13?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Chatam%20Sofer&lang2=en)

Why does the Torah refer to an animal organ, lacking in humans? Why not "heel" as in "הוּא יְשׁוּפְךָ רֹאשׁ וְאַתָּה תְּשׁוּפֶנּוּ עָקֵב"?

Comment: Possible Purim Torah answer, possibly serious: maybe He planned for when we'd say this on Rosh Hashana over some food!

Comment: the text made a negative association with the z-n-b root closely beforehand (Dev 25:18) אֲשֶׁר קָרְךָ בַּדֶּרֶךְ וַיְזַנֵּב בְּךָ כָּל הַנֶּחֱשָׁלִים so being a zanav wasn't a good thing.

Comment: The tail follows the head, but does not direct it. The feet direct the body. (Cf. *Pirkei Avos* 4:15, "רַבִּי מַתְיָא בֶן חָרָשׁ אוֹמֵר הֱוֵי מַקְדִּים בִּשְׁלוֹם כָּל אָדָם וֶהֱוֵי זָנָב לָאֲרָיוֹת וְאַל תְּהִי רֹאשׁ לַשּׁוּעָלִים").